# Can PHP running on a remote server handle files on my computer?

Tags: php

I'm very new to programming, I know only HTML/CSS. I have an idea, I want to make a ittle more dynamic website. I want to find the programming language that suits my needs. The website I imagined should have a function like that:

If I go to the website there's a button. If I click on that button, theh website displays the files and folders of my local hard drive, for example my computer's C: partition. After that if I click on a file or folder, the program deletes that file.

Can PHP running on remote server handle local files like that? Can PHP program access my files from a remote server? If the answer is 'yes', could you help me with little code snippet, how can PHP do that, which part of the language can handle this situation?
Or do I have to choose another programing language?
(I ask about PHP because it seems to be the "first step" towards making dynamic websites and it's for general use. It would be good not to learn a very specific programming language as my first programming language...)

Comment: No it cannot. PHP is a server side language.

Comment: why would you want something running on a remote server to delete files on your local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can't. You will need some java applet plus certified authorization or some VBScript with client approval. PHP ran only at server side and return the result as html to the web client

Answer (score 1):

No. The remote server can only handle files you explicitly upload to it.